# Synchronize a DataSet and DataTables with Database

Tags: .net, ado.net

I am using ADO.net with a DataSet and DataTables for the first time and I have run into a pretty significant problem. Each time that I change anything in my database table definitions, I don't seem to have an easy way to synchronize these changes to my DataTable definitions in my DataSet.

So far, it has been quick to simply delete my DataTable object and drag a new one over from the Server Explorer and recreate my queries. But as my application grows, this will soon become impossible. I also don't want to have to log every single change to the database and remember to change those definitions in each respective column in any affected DataTables.

For the record, I am using VS 2008, MySQL 5.0, ASP.net. ADO.net is my data provider, and I am really regretting it. Thanks.

Comment: Does your underlying data model really change that much?

Answer (score 1):

Update: This did not work as per Mathew. Leaving my post here until a better solution comes along.

It seems there is a configure option on DataTable context menu, which should trigger a [schema refresh](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=428338&SiteID=1). Can you try it out and let us know?

Comment: I followed the instructions in the URL. Totally didn't work. I changed the length of a varchar column and the DataTable did not pick it up when I went through the 'Config' context menu after the change.